# Is there a formula for the 95% confidence interval for the Skellam distribution or difference of two Poisson r.v.'s?

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, differences

I have two independent Poisson random variables and want to assess the confidence bounds for X - Y. I know there is a closed form solution for Poisson confidence bounds, but need the difference. Can I calculate this numerically for given Poisson failure rates. For example, suppose X ~ Poisson(20) and Y ~ Poisson(18). Can I generate samples from X and Y, subtract and find the quantiles at .025 and .975? Or similarly, generate samples from the Skillam(20,18) and find the .025 and .975 quantiles?

Comment: Personally I would be interested in the quantile function rather than a confidence interval, but you do you. Unfortunately there is a [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions) in the probability mass function that depends on $k$ which makes directly solving for $k$ difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably get away with the typical

$$ \bar{x} \pm z_{1-\alpha/2} \dfrac{\widehat{s}}{\sqrt{n}} \>. $$

The poisson with $\lambda\approx 20$ is very nearly normal (see below)

[image]

so you can approximate the Skellam as a normal with $\mu= 2$ and $\sigma^2 = 38$.

[image]

The coverage should be very good due to the reasonable approximation

```
library(tidyverse)

r <- map_dfr(1:100, ~{
  x <- rpois(50, 20)
  y <- rpois(50, 18)
  xbar <- mean(x) - mean(y)
  sd <- sqrt(var(x)/50 + var(y)/50) 
  
  tibble(xbar, ymin=xbar - 1.96*sd, ymax=xbar + 1.96*sd) %>% 
    mutate(covered = (ymin<2)&(ymax>2))
  
})

r %>% 
  mutate(i = seq_along(xbar)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(i, xbar, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, color=covered)) + 
  geom_pointrange() + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=2))
```

[image]

Comment: Overall good exposition, and suggesting a good approximation is helpful (+1). A nitpick about the distribution plots is that the Skellam and Poisson have PMFs rather than PDFs (i.e. density), but I am pretty sure you know that.

Comment: Meh, no harm no foul.

Comment: Also, formally [a PMF is a PDF (with respect to counting measure)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419557/419573#419573).