# What is the quantile function of a Skellam distribution?

Tags: quantiles, skellam-distribution

Reading [*Is there a formula for the 95% confidence interval for the Skellam distribution or difference of two Poisson r.v.'s?*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/638163/is-there-a-formula-for-the-95-confidence-interval-for-the-skellam-distribution), I realized that [I would rather have the quantile function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/638163/is-there-a-formula-for-the-95-confidence-interval-for-the-skellam-distribution#comment1192675_638163). Unfortunately [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) indicates a modified Bessel function of the first kind is in the probability mass function, which means I don't know how to directly solve for $k$.

Being able to compute prediction intervals for Skellam-distributed regression models could be handy in business, healthcare and physics (as well as other fields I am sure).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quantile function of the [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) is available as the `qskellam` function in the [`skellam` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=skellam) in `R`.  Because the distribution is a discrete distribution on the integers, it is relatively simple to program simply by comparing the cumulative sum of probabilities up to a quantile to the probability input for the quantile function.  Calculation of the quantile function does indeed involve computation of the modified Bessel function but that is also programmed in `R`.

---

If you want to generate an algorithm to compute the quantile function from scratch (especially a vectorised version of the quantile function), a reasonable approach would be to compute the distribution function at some low value and then compute increments for the mass function from this lower bound.  The latter can be computed using a recursive method that only requires you to compute two in initial mass values.  If we start with the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) $I_k$, this function satisfies the recursion:

$$I_k(2 \sqrt{\mu_1 \mu_2})
= I_{k-2}(2 \sqrt{\mu_1 \mu_2}) - \frac{k-1}{\sqrt{\mu_1 \mu_2}} \cdot I_{k-1}(2 \sqrt{\mu_1 \mu_2}).$$

The corresponding recursion for the mass function of the Skellam distribution is:

$$\begin{align}
f(k)
&\equiv \text{Skellam}(k|\mu_1,\mu_2) \\[12pt]
&= I_k(2 \sqrt{\mu_1 \mu_2}) \cdot \bigg( \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2} \bigg)^{k/2}  e^{-\mu_1-\mu_2} \\[6pt]
&= \bigg[ I_{k-2}(2 \sqrt{\mu_1 \mu_2}) - \frac{k-1}{\sqrt{\mu_1 \mu_2}} \cdot I_{k-1}(2 \sqrt{\mu_1 \mu_2}) \bigg] \bigg( \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2} \bigg)^{k/2} e^{-\mu_1-\mu_2} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2} \cdot I_{k-2}(2 \sqrt{\mu_1 \mu_2}) \cdot \bigg( \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2} \bigg)^{(k-2)/2} e^{-\mu_1-\mu_2} \\[6pt]
&\quad \quad - \frac{k-1}{\mu_2} \cdot I_{k-1}(2 \sqrt{\mu_1 \mu_2}) \cdot \bigg( \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2} \bigg)^{(k-1)/2} e^{-\mu_1-\mu_2} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2} \cdot \text{Skellam}(k-2|\mu_1,\mu_2) - \frac{k-1}{\mu_2} \cdot \text{Skellam}(k-1|\mu_1,\mu_2). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Now, suppose you first compute the values $f(x_0-1)$, $f(x_0)$ and $F(x_0)$ for some value $x_0$ such that $F(x_0)<p$ (or less than the minimum probability in a vectorised set of inputs).  Once you have done this initial computation (which requires computation of the modified Bessel function and do a single computation of the Skellam CDF) you can then write any quantile above the specified lower bound as:

$$\begin{align}
Q(p)
&= \min \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} | F(x) \geqslant p \} \\[18pt]
&= \min \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} | F(x_0) + [F(x) - F(x_0)] \geqslant p \} \\[12pt]
&= \min \Bigg\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} \Bigg| F(x_0) + \sum_{k = x_0+1}^x f(k) \geqslant p \Bigg\}. \\[4pt]
\end{align}$$

The terms in the sum can be computed recursively from $f(x_0-1)$ and $f(x_0)$ so it should be reasonably efficient to compute the quantiles of a set of input probabilities using a simple `while` loop with increments computed recursively.

Comment: For Pythonistas, [`scipy.stats.skellam`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skellam.html) has a method for the quantiles.